# How to pass data between activities in Andoid Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass data between 2 activities. I used the login Fragment template from Android studio and that is why I am working with the .navigate instead of the usual Intent. Is there a way to pass the username to MainActivity2 like this?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   NavHostFragment.findNavController(LoginFragment.this)
        .navigate(R.id.action_to_MainActivity2);
}
```

```
    <action android:id="@+id/action_to_MainActivity2"
            app:destination="@+id/mobile_navigation"/>
    </fragment>
    <activity android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
            tools:layout="@layout/activity_main2"
            android:name="com.example.runandcycle.MainActivity2"
        />
```

Comment: If you are using the Navigation component, see here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Answer (score 0):

Xml Code

```
 <action android:id="@+id/startMyFragment"
        app:destination="@+id/myFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="myArg"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="1" />
    </action>
```

Fragment Code

```
val args: ConfirmationFragmentArgs by navArgs()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val tv: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAmount)
    val amount = args.amount
    tv.text = amount.toString()
}
```

> The Navigation component has a Gradle plugin called Safe Args that
> generates simple object and builder classes for type-safe navigation
> and access to any associated arguments. Safe Args is strongly
> recommended for navigating and passing data, because it ensures
> type-safety.
>
> In some cases, for example if you are not using Gradle, you can't use
> the Safe Args plugin. In these cases, you can use Bundles to directly
> pass data.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        val nav_version = "2.4.2"
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
}
```

> To add Safe Args to your project, include the following classpath in
> your top level build.gradle file: